# What is the point of setClickable(true) on a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I copied some code from the web, it had setClickable(true) on the listview, however after commenting it out the listview is still clickable and reacts...

So what is the point of that method? can I safely remove it?

Comment: We'd need to see some code to help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for clickable is true, so this won't have any effect if there is no place in code where clickable is set to false.

So if you're sure this is not done anywhere, removing it won't have any effect.